# Multithreading deadlock issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock

Update:
I am not a regular StackOverflow user so apologies but I can't see a way to email this privately to the moderators
I think it was very unfair and heavy handed to lock this thread as being off topic and saying I must post example code etc. I already explained it is a big complex App, I would have to post dozens of lines of code, it would be incomprehensible to everyone. Not all software problems are simple enough to boil down to 10 lines of example code !

The fundamental problem is an architectural one, I tried my best to explain I have 2 async threads that need to lock two resources, then those 2 locks are also
accessed in the main thread. Because of the async nature. I cant see how I can control the lock orders and interleaving of the two locks to always guarantee no deadlocks.

Yes as suggested I could make just 1 lock to lock everything, but the performance hit would be very bad, so I cant really choose this simple solution.
I was hoping there is a more performant classic solution when you need multiple locks in an async scenario.

Thanks anyways for the replies I did get, before it was closed, I appreciate your time and help in these difficult times.

Regards

---

I am writing a fairly big App in C#, it has 2 asynchronous threads, one receiving an item price data stream, and one receiving an order detail stream.

Each of these threads builds a list of the incoming price/order data, each using their own ReaderWriterLockSlim. Set in write lock mode while the incoming data is moved to the lists.

The frequency of the incoming streams is very varied and unpredictable, sometimes the item price packets can be coming in at 10 ish millisec intervals, so I need to code this efficiently else it gets very sluggish.

Originally I was just reading the lists in the main thread (ReaderWriterLockSlim read lock), this worked fine.
However I now have a requirement where in the main thread I sometimes need to make some writes to both of the data lists.
Yes you guessed it, with the extra write locks, I am now getting random deadlocks, this I am pretty sure is the classic deadlock caused by interleaving access to 2 separate locks.

Because of the very async nature of my incoming data, I cannot predict when these threads will be write or read locking the lists, in relation to whatever processing my main thread is doing on the two lists.

As far as I can see, this is always going to be prone to deadlocking. I am horribly stuck on how I might change the architecture to solve this deadlock issue.

I would be really grateful if anyone could offer some thoughts on how this problem might be solved.

---

Code example. One thread runs this code:

```
lock (locker1)
{
    list1.Add("Something");
    lock (locker2)
    {
        list2.Add("Something");
    }
}
```

...while at the same time another thread runs this code:

```
lock (locker2)
{
    list2.Add("Something");
    lock (locker1)
    {
        list1.Add("Something");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid the ensuing deadlocks, without introducing restrictions in the order that the locks are taken?

Comment: Is it an option to use a single `ReaderWriterLockSlim` for both lists?

Comment: I feel your pain, but this is how things work here. Anyone with [3.000 reputation points or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) can cast a close vote, and 3 close votes are enough for a question to be closed. A question can then be reopened if 3 members with the same privilege cast a reopen vote. In practice it is hard to have your question reopened, and you must improve it greatly for this to happen, and it's not guaranteed. Personally I think that your question is quite good, although probably unsolvable. But unsolvable problems have the right to exist too. 

Comment: I edited your question and added a code example. Feel free to undo it if it deviates from the original intent of the post.

Comment: You could mitigate the problem of deadlocks by using the [`ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.tryenterwritelock) that accepts a timeout. In case of timeout it's probably a deadlock, so release all locks and try again.

Comment: I posted a solution for a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424306/solution-to-deadlock-lock-ordering/69785085#69785085) were you can simply replace `lock(lockObject){ ... }` with `using(LockOrderDeadlockResolver(lockObject)){ ... }` and the deadlock will be resolved automatically.

Answer (score 2):

(1) it's hard to tell where the problem is when you describe the code instead of showing it.

(2) in >80% of the cases a deadlock occurs when you have multiple locks locked by various threads in wrong order, for example: you have locks A,B,C and thread 1 tries to gather locks for A,B,C at the same time, and thread 2 tries to gather locks for B,A,C.

Ensure that all threads lock their locks in the same order. Even if one of the threads doesn't need 'A', ensure the other locks are taken in order.

(Note that in examples below ABC means that a thread tries to take ALL of them before releasing any. It means "lock A, lock B, lock C, do something, release all three")

These may deadlock from time to time:

- thread1: AB, thread2: BA
- thread1: ABC, thread2: BAC
- thread1: ABC, thread2: CAB

That's because there's a chance that one thread takes B and waits for A, while other thread takes A and waits for B.

On the other hand, these will NEVER deadlock:

- thread1: A, thread2: AB
- thread1: A, thread2: ABC
- thread1: AB, thread2: BC
- thread1: ABC, thread2: ABC
- thread1: ABC, thread2: AC
- thread1: BC, thread2: ABC

This is because locks are taken strictly in the same order. There's no way a thread could try taking A while already holding B, and so on.

In case it's not obvious, the basic rule is that strict ordering of attempts to lock things is what prevents deadlock, hence either: (a) lock only one thing at time, and unlock it before taking any other lock, or (b) make sure that all resources needed by given operation are always obtained in a strict order - you have an operation that locks three lists? make sure that those lists are always locked in the same order. Are 3 out of 100 lists needed at random? Never mind. Order them. Make sure they are locked in the same order. If in pinch, use their IDs, names, or even addresses, whatever, just make sure that no thread tries locking list (N+1)th before list (N)th. This is a simple solution and may not be the best in performance, but it at least gives a good safe starting point, which does not enforce full serialization/etc, and where you can try out other schemes and/or diagnose other problems.

Answer (score -1):

One easy way that I can think of is to maintain a queue of messages to your main thread, where each message will contain stream from one of the two streams that you have and you can differentiate between the two streams based on another parameter in the message.

This way you will process one stream at a time and you wouldn't face any deadlock issues.